# Between partially and largely

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, adverbs

I want to say that

> This chapter is based partially on [a paper I coauthored]

but "partially" doesn't feel right because the overlap is maybe 60%.
But

> This chapter is based largely on [a paper I coauthored]

seems to suggest more overlap than actually occurs.
I feel a need for a word conveying
substantive overlap, but neither partially nor largely.
"Substantively" doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: So you're saying it's mostly based on that paper?  Sorry, can't think of a term.

Comment: @HotLicks: Hmm, "mostly." I have to admit that didn't come to mind. Maybe that's best... Thanks!

Comment: Although technically correct, "mostly", to me, connotes greater responsibility than "largely".

Comment: I'm partial to partly, personally - or to *in part*, which wins the ngrams sweepstakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about,

> *Much* of this chapter is based on [a paper I coauthored].

Comment: I like this rewording---Thanks!